# Application related settings cleared after app update

Tags: ios, settings

I am developing an app which uses settings bundle to store information. Few users who have updated to the latest version reported that  all the settings previously stored has been cleared. This hasn’t happened in previous versions and doesn't occur in iOS 8.x.x, only occurs in iOS 9.0.  I use NSUserDefaults API to read/write app settings.

Does anyone else experienced this problem? Or if you could you please let me know any causes for this problem and possible solutions.

Thank you.